# Long text increase maxlength

Tags: forms

I have added a textarea and i want to store more that 1024 characters in it. Long text is the field type that i have chosen but an error comes up saying :
**Keywords cannot be longer than 1024 characters but is currently "xx" characters long.**
I tried using **hook_form_alter** to increase the maxlength but it does not work. Also tried the **hook_form_field_ui_field_edit_form_alter** to change the length from 255 to 555 but no success.
Is there any other workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Field maxlength alter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_maxlength_alter) module

> - Creating an update hook that alters the field tables
> - Installing this module and simply edit the max_length in the admin    interface
> - Installing this module and run the Drush command to modify the    max_length

Comment: I tried using this module but option to increase Maximum length does not appear for textarea's. It comes up for textfields only.

Comment: That's because long text fields don't have a max length @KapilRopalekar, having such a setting wouldn't make sense. They use a `big text`, per [`text_field_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!text!text.install/function/text_field_schema/7), which in MySQL translates to a `LONGTEXT`, which has ~4GB of storage - considerably more than 1024 characters worth. Drupal core doesn't impose this limit, so you need to start disabling contrib modules one by one until you find which one is doing it. After that you can work out how to get around it